# Can the word "bully" be used as an "adjective"?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, phrases, adjectives

I want to write the sentence:

> Bill helped him when he needed to overthrow the current leader, who is a **bully**.

Is there anyway to make that sentence flow better? For example, can I somehow use the word *bully* as an **adjective**:

> ...when he needed to overthrow the **bully** leader.

And the sentence sounds odd. Which word can I use for better flow that would work in day-to-day language?

Comment: One would normally use *bullying* for the adjective form.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike some of the other answers I think you can get away with *bully leader*. You're not really using *bully* as an adjective but forming a noun phrase. However to me it means the leader of the bullies (rather like *gang leader*), not the *bullying leader* you seem to want.

Comment: In informal speech you could say “the current bully of a leader”

Comment: @Jim you certainly could,  or *bullying leader* as suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The word *bully* can be used as an adjective. But it does not mean what you think it means. Here is the [Wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bully#Adjective) of the adjective:

> 1. (US, slang) Very good; excellent.
> 2. (slang) Jovial and blustering; dashing.

In other words, the adjective and the noun form of the word have differing meanings.

If you are intent on using *bully* in this sentence, you could simply say:

> Bill helped him when he needed to overthrow the current bullying leader.

Or, with a new word:

> Bill helped him when he needed to overthrow the current intimidating leader.

Comment: `the current bullying leader.` indicates that he is bullying currently, instead of describing his personality. Right?

Comment: "the current bullying leader" can have two interpretations. 1) The current leader who is bullying. 2)  The bullying leader who is current.

Answer (score 1):

> > Bill helped him when he needed to overthrow the current leader, who is a **bully**.

The word *bully* isn't commonly used as an adjective in English. The phrase *the bully leader* doesn't work particularly well. For day-to-day language as opposed to formal writing, the Original Poster could try a construction called a *right dislocation*. This is when some noun-phrase is reiterated at the end of the sentence, but with a different phrasing. This noun phrase is normally the Subject or Complement of the verb. The reiteration normally clarifies the identity of the noun phrase in some way:

- I went to see Bob Marshall, the Managing Director.

In the sentence above the phrase *the Managing Director* gives us a more salient description of  Bob Marshall for the purposes of the story.

For the Original Poster's sentence, if they wanted to use a right dislocation they could try either of the following:

- Bill helped him when he needed to overthrow the current leader, a ferocious bully.
- Bill helped him when he needed to overthrow a bully, the current leader of XYZ.

I'm not sure that the adjective *current* works here. *Current* usually refers to the time of speaking. If the bully is the current leader, then it would seem that he hasn't been overthrown. The Original Poster might with to use the modifier *then* instead, or use the adjective *previous*:

- Bill helped him when he needed to overthrow a bully, the previous leader of XYZ.
- Bill helped him when he needed to overthrow a bully, the then leader of XYZ.

The adjective *previous* seem to work better, in my opinion.

Comment: Although there is [bully pulpit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bully_pulpit)

Comment: @Jim Indeed so! :)

Answer (score -1):

Bill helped him overthrow the current leader who was a bully.